# Remove User type picklist on lookup field in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I imagine this isn't possible, but is there any way to remove or override the User type pick-list that shows up when User look-up field is associated with an apex:inputField? See screen cap:

[image: User type pick-list]

I'm asking because 1. a standard user will always be selected and 2. real-estate on this page is a little tight and I'd like to trim where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through the [attribute list](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) for `apex:inputField`, I don't see anything that looks like it'll help.

Here's what I suggest: (if using Chrome) right-click and select <kbd>Inspect Element</kbd> over the User-type picklist, and see if there's a specific class attached to that element.  Then using jQuery, in your `.ready` function, hide all elements of that class.  Hopefully, the class name for user-type picklists is unique, so it won't bother any other part of the page.

**Example:**  If the class name for user-type picklists = "`userType`", have the following jQuery

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery)}"/>
<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$('.userType').hide(); 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback and code snippet. I figured I could use jQuery to manually target those pick-list fields and hide them, but I was asking more-so from a Salesforce perspective if it there's some "hack" we can put in the VF element attributes, or something else that can be written into the page controller, etc. I'll give this a whirl though. Thanks again!

Comment: they might add an attribute in the future to help with this issue, but going through the attributes currently available, I don't see anything that could be useful.

Comment: you can always use your own HTML inputs, but then you lose (or have to create-on-your-own) the lookup.  really, I think the jQuery solution is easiest to implement

Comment: I'm just being extremely lazy and wanted to avoid writing three simple lines of jQuery! :] Unfortunately Visualforce doesn't assign the select field a CSS class, but though the markup does give it an Id ending in mlktp, so I changed the hide line to: $j("[id$=mlktp]").hide();